# First a tag created in a Javascript loop not implemented

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate a div (class='thumb") with thumnailpictures. The name of the pictures is gathered from an xml file. Every thumnail picture is encapsulated with an a-tag that points to a function to show the full picture.

On some browsers the first thumbnailpicture seems not to have this a-tag...clicking on it gives no action...

```
var rubriek = gup('rubriek'), // rubriek is a parameter in the url of this page pointing a specific photogallery
    gallerij = rubriek + "gallery.xml",
    xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc(gallerij),
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("filename"),
    legebron = x[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var beeldnummer = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        index = i + 1,
        kleinbeeld = "/" + rubriek + "images/thumb/" + beeldnummer;

    $('.thumb').append('<p><a class="kleintje" onclick="toonDezeFoto(&quot;' + beeldnummer + '&quot;,' + index + ',' + x.length + ');">
<img src="' + kleinbeeld + '" id="' + index + '">
</a></p>');
}
```

See http://www.karinedaelman.be/foto.php?rubriek=Mensen/

Found the solution: the z-index of the div that keeps the thumbnails was too low. Another div that has the site logo in it had a higher z-index and a width of 100%. Because of that the first thumbnail image was on a layer below the site logo and could not be accessed by the mouseevents....

Comment: Can you define 'Some browsers'?

Comment: Yes: 
Safari, Firefox and IE9 give no a tag on the first thumbnail. Chrome is OK. 
Strange thing is that IE on a windows7 phone and Safari on iPod is also OK (= gives the a tag on the first thumbnail).

Comment: Sounds like it might be an indexing problem, have you tried with just "index = i" instead of "index = i + 1" just to rule that out. Without seeing the whole case I cant help anymore than that, hopefully someone else can.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it myself in the meantime. It was a layer-related problem. I have edited the question and explained the 'solution' there.